# Creating array/matrix with parameters

Tags: python, parameters, schedule, frames

**Context** 
I am an architect (also, relatively new to python) and I am trying to create a schedule that tells my partner and I which spaces to view at certain times throughout the day over 5 days.

**Parameters**
- x axis: 30 minute intervals over 8 hours
- y axis: different spaces (18 total)
- Every space must be viewed 2x/day (1x per person)
- Every space must be viewed at different times over 5 days

**Help**
I'm having trouble getting started. I initially started with Numpy matrices then data frames, however, I think it is a bit more complex than that; I think it is more of a ML problem. Furthermore, as I break the problem down, I am assuming I need to write an algorithm to pass within the function(?) in order to capture the viewing parameters.

Any advice on where to look? How to get started? I want to challenge myself to do it but need some guidance on where to start. Anything helps!

Thanks

Comment: Scheduling, in general, is a challenging computational problem to solve. I think a good place to start would be to look at some implementations on GitHub: https://github.com/topics/scheduling-algorithms?l=python.

Comment: thank you - very much appreciated!